# Cannot use this in the arguement passing in a method in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, this

I am using below format to pass arguement to a redux thunk function:

```
handleComment(dishId){
        console.log(this.state);
        this.props.dispatch(postComment({dishId,this.state.author,this.state.comment,new Date().toISOString()}))
    }
```

But it is saying unexpected keyword `this`. However, console.log statement is running fine. Why does this error appears? Can anybody guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unexpected keyword usually means that what you wrote isn't actually javascript.

```
// This is not an object, objects have keys and values
{
  dishId,
  this.state.author,
  this.state.comment,
  new Date().toISOString()
}

// This is an object
{
  dishId,
  author: this.state.author,
  comment: this.state.comment,
  date: new Date().toISOString()
}
```